# syntax error ( *EngineEdition != 11) (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

Tags: sql-server-2017

I am getting this error message from our sql server. The error went away once I restart the server. Just wondering what could have caused it.
[image]

Comment: I go this error too. No idea what it means, but I received it after restoring a copy of a database (which had it's own errors). I suspect something was weird with the database files since that is what I had to trouble shoot to get the copy restored. Either that, or when the database got stuck in a restore state and I restored a second time caused it.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed in SSMS 18.11 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15